# change filename to yyymmddhhmmss in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Well, I'm a Linux newbie, and I'm having an issue with a simple bash script.

I have over 4++ file. Everthing files live from store their send EOD (End Of Day) to tectia. Example filename is `POLL91.DWN` and `POLL67.DWN` then i want to rename it to `xxxx.yyyymmddhhmmss.POLL91` (xxxx is the store name) and that should be like this

```
GSTD.20151228094505.POLL91

RJKS.20151228100539.POLL67
```

Comment: Where is the date coming from? The modified timestamp on the file, or current time? Or something else?

Comment: Also, it might help to know where these files live. Are they all in the same dir, or spread out in some manner?

Comment: Update your question with these new details.

Comment: @jdv is correct - we need more information to help solve your problem, and a [regular expression](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html) or a bulk renaming tool as mentioned are almost-certainly what you're looking for. However, the first step in your case is to back up what you're working on so nothing bad happens to the original, and possibly work in a copy. It is unwise to experiment on the "real data" if you're not certain what you're doing. Unfortunately, SO live chat requires 20 rep.

Answer (score 1):

This is asking a lot, to get a working solution for these loose requirements. Assuming you want to use the shell, you would have to iterate through the files, break up the parts of the name and create a new name that is used as an argument to the `mv` command.

I bet there are bulk renamers you can install from the usual sources. Maybe search the Ubuntu software repos for that string?

Otherwise, you are stuck walking the filenames, breaking them apart for the pieces you need, and then reassembling them into the strings you need to make the new filename.